# PHP concatenation skips line on empty value

Tags: php, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate an array, but when PHP comes across an empty array-item, it stops concatenating.

My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test1
            [1] => Test1
            [2] => 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test2
            [1] => Test2
            [2] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test3
            [1] => Test3
            [2] => Test3
        )
)
```

The 3th item on the first 2 Array-items are empty. And when I loop over them like this:

```
$keys = array('uid', 'type', 'some_column', 'other_column');
foreach ($csv as $i => $row) {
    $uid = $row[0] . $row[1] . $row[2];
    array_unshift($row, $uid);
    $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
}
```

I only get `Test3Test3Test3` back, instead of the expected

```
Test1Test1
Test2Test2
Test3Test3Test3
```

So it looks like PHP is skipping items when concatenating an empty value.
Is this normal PHP behavior? And if so, how can I tackle this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It below in the question. I expect an empty value of the array concatenated to the other values...

Comment: do you need the line break or you don't

Comment: @DevZer0, no, not really

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$uid = array();
foreach ($array as $i => $row) {
    $uid[] = $row[0] . $row[1] . $row[2];
}
var_dump($uid);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Test1Test1
    [1] => Test2Test2
    [2] => Test3Test3Test3
)
```

You can do something similar to produce a string:

```
$uid = '';
foreach ($arr as $i => $row) {
    $uid .= $row[0] . $row[1] . $row[2] . "\n";
}
echo $uid;
```

Output:

```
Test1Test1
Test2Test2
Test3Test3Test3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I edited my question (I left out some code to ease the question), so maybe this helps understanding the question even better.

Comment: @Michiel - Your updated answer just throws errors. Can you explain what you really want.

Comment: I did another update on my question. The code quoted in the question is just a part of my function. The function concatenates a csv-file and I need the `$uid` to concatenate the first 3 items of each line.

Comment: @Michiel - I ran your code, and it gives an output without errors, but I have no idea what your expected output is. You have a concatenated value for uid just like you said. So what's your question?

Comment: Yes, I have a concatenated value. But in some cases `$row[2]` is empty, and then the whole `$uid` is empty as well... And that's what I'm trying to avoid!

Comment: @Michiel - I don't now what you mean. When `$row[2]` is empty, `$uid` is not empty; it contains `$row[0].$row[1]`.

Comment: That what I figured, but for some reason, the `$uid` keeps empty when `$row[2]` is empty... Very strange!

Comment: @Michiel - You could try running your code here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ just to see if your setup is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$uid = array();
foreach ($array as $i => $row) {
    $uid[] = $row[0] . $row[1] . $row[2];
}
var_dump($uid);
```

Just you are giving `$uid` and it is taking it as an type `variable` and it appends the **last occurance** of loop into that variable.If you want your desired output you need to declare it as an `array` before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I edited my question (I left out some code to ease the question), so maybe this helps understanding the question even better.

Comment: You can get it from mine and Pé de Leão ans

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but if *that* is your desired output, you're overcomplicating things:

```
$foo = array(
    array("Test1","Test1"),
    array("Test2","Test2"),
    array("Test3","Test3","Test3")
);
echo implode(PHP_EOL,
             //implode all child arrays, by mapping, passes no delimiter
             //behaves as concatenation
             array_map('implode',$foo)
);
```

Returns:

```
Test1Test1
Test2Test2
Test3Test3Test3
```

In your case, you can use bits of this code like so:

```
$csv = array(array("Test1","Test1",''),array("Test2","Test2",''),array("Test3","Test3","Test3"));
$keys = array('uid', 'type', 'some_column', 'other_column');
foreach($csv as $k => $row)
{
    array_unshift($row,implode('',$row));
    $csv[$k] = array_combine($keys,$row);
}
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uid] => Test1Test1
            [type] => Test1
            [some_column] => Test1
            [other_column] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => Test2Test2
            [type] => Test2
            [some_column] => Test2
            [other_column] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => Test3Test3Test3
            [type] => Test3
            [some_column] => Test3
            [other_column] => Test3
        )

)
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bit more complicated. The code I've quoted in my question is just a part of my function. The function concatenates a CSV and I need the `$uid` to be the concatenation of the first 3 items of the `$csv`...

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected output

```
$uid = "";
foreach ($array as $i => $row) {
    $uid .= $row[0] . $row[1] . $row[2] . "\n";
}
echo $uid;
```

Comment: I edited my question (I left out some code to ease the question), so maybe this helps understanding the question even better.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but not what I'm looking for. See my edited question in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: where did your `$keys` come from.

Comment: Somewhere else in the code. But the `$keys` are fine/working, so that's not something to worry about...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two `foreach` loop..

Procedure:

1. Initialize your first foreach loop to get the `key => value as $key=> $value` of each array inside.
2. Then initialize your second loop to `$value` variable since value inside of this is another array `key => value` = `$innerKey => $innerValue`.
3. Then inside your second loop echo $innerValue to display values inside of the secondary array
4. Lastly put an `echo '<br/>'` inside your first loop to put each secondary array into another newline.`

.

```
$data = array(
                0 => array(
                    0 => 'Test1',
                    1 => 'Test1',
                    2 => ''
                ),
                1 => array(
                     0 => 'Test2',
                     1 => 'Test2',
                     2 => ''
                ),
                2 => array(
                     0 => 'Test3',
                     1 => 'Test3',
                     2 => 'Test3'
                )
            );

   foreach($data as $key => $value){
       foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue){
           echo $innerValue;

       }
       echo '<br/>';

   }

// Output would be..
Test1Test1
Test2Test2
Test3Test3Test3
```

Code Tested at : [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)